# What is DataType R8, I2 and likes?

Tags: xml, types

I am trying to create an XML to be sent as request to a SOAP API. In the documentation its written,

[image]

What exactly are these types?

The only google result I got is: http://forums.asp.net/t/703915.aspx?what+datatype+is+it+dt+type+r8+ How correct is this?

Comment: I'm going to guess they're integer and real (ie float), with the relevant number of bytes.

Comment: @Spudley: specific datatype like short, int, long? Ain't the numbers 2 and 8 significant?

Comment: yes; I guessed they were the number of bytes.

Comment: got the answer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling quite a bit, I got the answer. Posting it for future reference.

I2 = SMALLINT
R8 = DOUBLE

The entire table

[image]

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724344(v=vs.85).aspx